# Addition of the total cumulative data genrated from particular Ips

Tags: linux, perl, shell, awk, sed

I have a list of data containing two colums.One of the Ip from which the mail was sent and other column contains the total bytes that were sent through the mail.
I want a cumulative total of all the data that has been transfered through a particular ip.
Suppose that there are 4 entries:

```
192.168.0.100 40k
192.168.0.123 20k
192.168.0.100 15k
192.168.0.240 20k
```

Then, the output should be:

```
192.168.0.100 55k
192.168.0.123 20k
192.168.0.240 20k
```

Answer (score 4):

This makes it:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END { for (i in a) print i, a[i]"k"}' file
192.168.0.123 20k
192.168.0.100 55k
192.168.0.240 20k
```

#### Explanation

- `{a[$1]+=$2}` store the cumulative values in the array `a[]`, whose index is the first field of the row.
- `END { for (i in a) print i, a[i]"k"}` loop through values printing the totals. Note `k` has to be specifically printed.

Comment: +1 even though I haven't read the Q & A.  what I saw the Q was asked `1 min ago`, and the answer was answered `23 secs aga`. !!! fedorqui, are you a machine? :D

Comment: @AvinashRaj `a[]` stores sums, and after addition there is no `k` in it.

Comment: There is no default, @AvinashRaj, values will be created by the time you do the assignment. But if you for example just do `awk '{a[$1]}'` then the values will be created but with empty value. Check `awk '{a[$1]} END {for (i in a) print i " ==> " a[i]}' file` for example.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks for your info. Is there any separate chat room for bash?

Comment: @AvinashRaj not that I am aware of (in general, I don't use them). Maybe the chats from http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to awk solution, `}{` being perl shortcut for `END{}` block

```
perl -anE'$h{$F[0]} += $_ for /(\d+)k$/ }{say "$_ $h{$_}k" for sort keys %h' file
```

Comment: QQ: Any particular reason to use regex instead of `+=$F[1]`?

Comment: @jaypal `+=$F[1]` would complain under `warnings` for not being a number.

Comment: Oh, good to know. Thanks @mpapec. I had already upvoted your answer so I can only upvote your comment now! `:)`

Comment: is `}{` being a shortcut for an `END {}` block documented anywhere?

Comment: @Miller it is not real END block, but code which follows the loop. Check [perlsec](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Eskimo-greeting)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much mail is sent by each of these addresses, but ignoring the suffix might cause problems down the line. Here is one way to handle it with awk and `numfmt`, a recent addition to GNU coreutils:

```
# Lowercase k is a non-standard suffix and not supported by numfmt 
<file awk '$2=toupper($2)'  |

# We assume the k is IEC encoded, i.e. k=1024. Use --from=si if 1000 was intended
numfmt --field=2 --from=iec |

# Perform the summation, same as in @fedorqui's answer
awk '{ h[$1]+=$2 } END { for(k in h) print k, h[k] }' |

# Add appropriate suffixes. Again change to --to=si if k=1000
numfmt --field=2 --to=iec
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.100   55K
192.168.0.123   20K
192.168.0.240   20K
```